# Why does my AJAX call of JSON object returns undefined for its specific contents?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have an AJAX request here:

```
    var model = $("#variation").val();
    var problem_id = $('input[name="problem"]:checked').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../common/prices.php",
        data: {model: model, problem_id: problem_id},
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data['bronze_price']);

        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error: Contact administrator");
         }

    });
```

and the end result is some sort of array.

```
console.log(data)
```

returns `{"bronze_price":null,"silver_price":null,"gold_price":"249.00"}`, by the way

This is the PHP code:

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ext_product_price WHERE product_id='".$_POST['model']."' AND problem_id='".$_POST['problem_id']."'";

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        die(json_encode(array("bronze_price"=> $row['bronze_price'], "silver_price"=>$row['silver_price'], "gold_price"=>$row['gold_price'])));
```

So, data['bronze_price'] returns "undefined" but when I remove all parameters it displays the array `{"bronze_price":null,"silver_price":null,"gold_price":"249.00"}`. I want to access each individual piece of data (bronze_price, silver_price, gold_price). All answers and comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` log at `console`?

Comment: @guest271314 it returns `"{\"bronze_price\":null,\"silver_price\":null,\"gold_price\":\"249.00\"}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following json header to return json with a valid content type

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

die(json_encode(array("bronze_price"=> $row['bronze_price'], "silver_price"=>$row['silver_price'], "gold_price"=>$row['gold_price'])));
```

you can use the dot notation to get the values

```
alert(data.bronze_price);
```

make sure you are returning the correct json structure

Comment: I recently changed it. When I console.log(data), it returns `{"bronze_price":null,"silver_price":null,"gold_price":"249.00"}`, so does this answer still apply?

Comment: the last line of the answer still applies  :))

Comment: are you sure you have the table rows name `bronze_price` and `silver_price` do they have values in the db?

Comment: yea those are intentionally empty. Once i added the header it returned null instead of undefined and the gold_price table returned a real value. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It will be `data.bronze_price`. Others looking OK.